# Should I be worried about this url request I received on my site?

Tags: http, javascript, injection, iis

I was checking the weekend logs of my IIS server and noticed a strange request which was blocked:

```
http://www.mysite.com/Scripts,j.html()).html(a.spinner)}this.xhr=d.ajax(d.extend({},a.ajaxOptions,{url:h,success:function(k,n){e.element.find(e._sanitizeSelector(c.hash)).html(k);e._cleanup();a.cache&&d.data(c
```

I have checked my scripts folder and found nothing unusual. I also I searched part of the request on Google and found that it is some kind of 'javascript injection'.

Should I be worried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I googled the query, I received many similar requests reported as malicious on different websites (like [this one](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/forumid/108/threadid/458333/scope/posts)). This certainly looks like an XSS attempt. However, I don't think there's anything to worry about this particular request. The code:

```
j.html()).html(a.spinner)}this.xhr=d.ajax(d.extend({},a.ajaxOptions,{url:h,success:function(k,n){e.element.find(e._sanitizeSelector(c.hash)).html(k);e._cleanup();a.cache&&d.data(c
```

is actually a part of [jQuery UI 1.8.13 minified](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js). This is basically a part of the code which is responsible for handling [Tab Widgets](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/). Here is the complete code:

```
        if ( o.spinner ) {
            var span = $( "span", a );
            span.data( "label.tabs", span.html() ).html( o.spinner );
        }

        this.xhr = $.ajax( $.extend( {}, o.ajaxOptions, {
            url: url,
            success: function( r, s ) {
                self.element.find( self._sanitizeSelector( a.hash ) ).html( r );

                // take care of tab labels
                self._cleanup();

                if ( o.cache ) {
                    $.data( a, "cache.tabs", true );
                }

                self._trigger( "load", null, self._ui( self.anchors[ index ], self.panels[ index ] ) );
                try {
                    o.ajaxOptions.success( r, s );
                }
                catch ( e ) {}
            },
            error: function( xhr, s, e ) {
                // take care of tab labels
                self._cleanup();

                self._trigger( "load", null, self._ui( self.anchors[ index ], self.panels[ index ] ) );
                try {
                    // Passing index avoid a race condition when this method is
                    // called after the user has selected another tab.
                    // Pass the anchor that initiated this request allows
                    // loadError to manipulate the tab content panel via $(a.hash)
                    o.ajaxOptions.error( xhr, s, index, a );
                }
                catch ( e ) {}
            }
        } ) );
```

There are also no existing vulnerabilities specific to this particular version of jQuery UI. I don't think it would have done anything malicious, at least on the server side.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will check the site traffic and see if there's anything suspicious. Will let you know as soon as I get the info.

Comment: Sure. Please do post your findings here. This request has appeared at various other places as well. I would definitely like to know the mystery behind this request.